# No data in response for a ajax action in ZF2 Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

The problem is that I don't have data in controller, in filterAction function.

I can see in firebug at Post:

```
Source: daterange=2015%2F10%2F22+-+2015%2F10%2F22
```

at Response:

```
 {"daterange":null,"submit":null}
```

In the response at daterange I want to be the date range which I introduced in interface.

Here is the ajax call

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#incidents').bind("submit",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var urlform = '<?php echo $this->url('incidents', array('controller'=>'IncidentsController', 'action'=>'filter')); ?>';

            $.ajax({
                url: urlform,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                data: ($("#incidents").serialize()),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here's the Form:

```
    <?php
 namespace Incidents\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class IncidentsForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('incidents');
         $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');


        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'daterange',
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Start Time'
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Filter',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
     }
 }
```

Here is the filterAction() on the controller:

```
public function filterAction()
{
    $form = new IncidentsForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response   = $this->getResponse();

    if ($request->isPost()){
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $formData = $form->getData();
        }
    }

   return $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($formData));
}
```

I'm expecting that in $formData to have the date range which I selected in interface from the daterangepicker control. 
Can some one help me, plese?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have to use $request->getContent() in place of using $request->getPost() since you use a json data type in your ajax call

Comment: It's true, I got data if I used getContent() function. But finally I changed the ajax call, deleted this 2 options: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true  And I optained what I wanted.